# Reference about direct image sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory, pushforward

I was searching in Internet but I was not able to find a proper book/notes/etc. in which are carried out explicit computations with direct image sheaves. In particular I was interested in examples (computations) of the form:

1. What is $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_Y$, where $\pi:Y \rightarrow X$ is a finite morphism?
2. If there is a Galois cover $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$, how can we use the action of the Galois group $G$ in order to decompose $\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_Y$?
3. How to compute explicitly $\pi_*\mathcal{F}$, where $\pi:Y \rightarrow X$ is a "nice" morphism and $\mathcal{F}$ is a "nice or famous" sheaf?

In particular any reference in which examples with coordinates and explicit calculations are carried out properly are much appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: For affine morphisms of schemes (in particular finite morphisms), pushforward means on every affine $\operatorname{Spec} A \cong U \subseteq X$ that $V = \pi^{-1}(U) \subseteq Y$ is affine open, say $V \cong \operatorname{Spec} B$, and $(\pi_*\mathcal O_Y)|_U$ is the quasicoherent sheaf associated to the $A$-module $B$. Likewise, if $\mathscr F$ is quasi-coherent, then $(\pi_* \mathscr F)|_U$ is the $B$-module $\mathscr F(V)$ viewed as $A$-module through the structure map $A \to B$. Any book on schemes (or spectra of rings) will discuss this at length.

Comment: Maybe try:  "Abelian covers of algebraic varieties."
Rita Pardini, Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (1991)   Volume: 417, page 191-214. Also the book by Esnault and Viehweg has some explicit computation for cyclic covers (with a view to vanishing theorems) see http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/esnault/books.html